# Mapping .mp4.001 and .mp4.002 files into a player

Tags: video, html5-video, video-capture, vlc, joiner

I have been looking for a way in which I can map two split files into an online player. For example if I have .mp4.001 file and .mp4.002 file in one folder VLC media player automatically finds all the connected files in the same folder and plays a complete uninterrupted video.

Now what I want is an online player ofcourse in HTML5 in which I can map all the files which are in different locations. 
eg.

```
src=http://www.xxx.xxx/abc.mp4.001
src=http://www.xys.xxx/abc.mp4.002
src=http://www.xyz.xxx/abc.mp4.003
```

I was not able to find any player also I am not sure if this is possible.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

`VLC` has a playlist, so you should implement a playlist for your `html5-video player`. [check here](http://www.videoplayerhtml5.com/).

Or you can use `javascript` to listen to the `html5 video on end event`, to decide which video should be played next.

Comment: Actually that is not possible. No player recognizes the .002 file. All will play the .001 file but playing other parts individually  is not possible even in VLC player. Remember i am splitting the video file and not a video.

Comment: Well, do you have to split them like this? if you would split them this way `http://www.xxx.xxx/abc_001.mp4` `http://www.xxx.xxx/abc_002.mp4` you could play them individually and implement your player like I recommended. if not, i'm out of ideas

Comment: actually, I have to split them according to the file size available in different places. Do you know any split utility which will split a video in different sizes?